# Replace the value in each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I wrote a macro that copies all files from a given folder with the extension .rpt to excel. Then creating a separate sheet for each product with  name of product.

**What I need?**

Now I need to create a panel in Steering Tab (columns L-N) that changes certain values ​​(from the table in steering tabs) in column B in each sheet, but I can't do it myself.

[image]

**The concept I came up with is as follows:**

I would like my macro to open each sheet separately and do the following tasks for each sheet:

1. Select the range from cell B4 to the end. (I already did it)

   ```
   Sub a()
       Dim i As Intiger
       i = Sheets(3).Range("B4").End(xlDown).row
       Sheets(3).Range("B4: B" & i).Select
   End Sub
   ```
2. Searched for values ​​in the selected range that are > 400 in column B of the each sheet
3. If the condition is true then it should read the values ​​from the table in the steering table in column L and if it finds the same SPcode then:

   a) copied the entire line to the bottom of the sheet

   b) did replace in cell B to the value in cell M from steering tab
4. Then it did an Offset of 6 cells to the side and changed the value to that specified in cell N (but I can already write it myself)

**Or second concept**

1. A function that Determines where the sheet ends (on which line) and assigns a variable eg endrow
2. Checks column B (spcode) in the sheet to see if there are values from the L column in steering
3. If the condition is true, then it copies the entire line of the spreadsheet with the values satisfying the condition down (under all data), ie under the endrow line - I can't write it totally.
4. In the copied line, changes the SP code to the new one from column M and Entry_month from the Steering Tab 5. Goes to the next sheet

Below are screenshots with view on tables
[image]

**Important thing to know is:**
I would like to be able to add an unlimited number of combinations in the steering tab

I am not an advanced programmer. If there are any questions, ask me on an ongoing basis. I will answer you. In the meantime, I will fight with it myself ;) But please help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. please note that this is not a free code writing service. So my question is "what is your question" i.e. what is the exact problem you are having with your code? If the answer is you don't know where to start, the answer is break down what needs to be done into individual steps, then code each one in turn. Side note You want to [avoid using select in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Just curious about your number-2 after reading your number-3.  Column B is the SpCode and you want to match the value under "Existing" with the value under SpCode whatever row. So, your number-2, why did you want to search SpCode rows which value > 400  ? is the data under "Existing" might be < 400 ? So if the data under "Existing" < 400 you want to skip the match process to the data under the SpCode? Please CMIIW.

Comment: Also, _"copied the entire line to the bottom of the sheet"_, did you mean to the end of the row of the sheet ? and then it will be replaced if the other data under "Existing" match the data under SpCode ? In other words, once the sub finish run, there will be one row with value which is the very end row of the sheet ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma Ad1: You're right, I'm just a professional deviation that "NewBusiness" spcodes are greater than 400, so I use it anyway. There is actually no handshake here and this operation is unnecessary :)

It may be that it just searches the values in column B and if it finds a value, it copies the entire row to the bottom of this sheet under the existing data and only changes the value of SPcode and Entry_month in them.

Comment: @karma Ad2:The exact process should look like this:
1. A function that Determines where the sheet ends (on which line) and assigns a variable eg endrow
2. Checks column B (spcody) in the sheet to see if there are values from the L column in steering
3. If the condition is true, then it copies the entire line of the spreadsheet with the values satisfying the condition down (under all data), ie under the endrow line - I can't write it totally.
4. In the copied line, changes the SP code to the new one from column M and Entry_month from the Steering Tab
5. Goes to the next sheet

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I know that this is not a "free coding platform" I am trying to write the whole program and 80% of the program is already written. And as far as I know, I can only ask 1 question a day :(

I just can't write a loop that will copy whole lines to the end of the sheet for the values listed in the steering tab.
This is the part that interests me the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub NBSPCODES()

Dim rgSteer As Range
Dim rg As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim RC As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim rgDest As Range
Dim MonthCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim cek As Boolean

'create the range of spcode as rgSteer variable
With Sheets("Config")
Set rgSteer = .Range("L4", .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

'loop to each sheets
For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name = "Config" Or sh.Name = "Summary" Then GoTo nxt 'skip the loop (too many end if so I reverse the if)
    
    'get the column number where the header value is ENTRY_MONTH as MonthCol variable
    'get the last column of the header as LC variable
        MonthCol = sh.Rows(2).Find("ENTRY_MONTH").Column
        LC = sh.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        
        'loop to each cell in rgSteer
        For Each cell In rgSteer
            
            'check if the looped cell value (spcode from sheet Configure) is found in the looped sheet column 2
            If Not sh.Columns(2).Find(cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
            'if it is found, then set a range as c variable to find the value of
            'spcode to be replaced (the looped cell.offset(0,1) value) is already in the looped sheet column 2 or not
                Set c = sh.Columns(2).Find(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, after:=sh.Range("B1"))
                    
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        'if found
                         'check if the entry_month from sheet Configure (looped cell.Offset(0,2) value
                        'is the same with the found cell (the c variable) row, MonthCol value - if same then have cek as false
                        If Cells(c.row, MonthCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value Then cek = False
                    Else
                        'if not found have cek variable as true
                        cek = True
                    End If
            End If
            
            'the below code will be processed if it does find the spcode from sheet Configure in the looped sheet column 2
            'but it doesn't find the spcode to be replaced and the entry_month from sheet Configure in the looped sheet
            If cek = True Then
                With sh.Columns(2)
                    .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, False, False
                    Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -1)
                    RC = Application.CountA(rg)
                    .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
                End With
        
                For i = 1 To LC - 1: Set rg = Union(rg, rg.Offset(0, 1)): Next i
            
                Set rgDest = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set rgDest = rgDest.Resize(RC, LC)
                rg.Copy Destination:=rgDest
                rgDest.Columns(2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                rgDest.Columns(MonthCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            End If
        
        Next

nxt:
Next sh
End Sub
```

FYI, if the value under "Existing" is not unique .... For example (based on your image of sheet config), you have 651 ... then this number is to be replaced with 661, entry month 4. if there is another 651 value under "Existing" and the replacing value is (for example) 123 - entry month 7, then the sub at the time the loop in rgSteer find the second 651, it will copy again those 651 range under SpCode, paste to rgDest and fill the rgDest column 2 replacement with 123. Which give you a result that now there are 2 similar data under the last row of the original data.... one with 661 SpCode entry month 4 and one with 123 SpCode entry month 7.

The code assumed that the SpCode data is not sorted. For example, under SpCode of the looped sheet, row 5 to 7 value is 651, row 100 value is 651, row 123 value is 651. That's why it use the union rather than set the rg from rg to rg.offset(0,LC-1).

Once again, **it's not tested in my side.**

Still, to be honest I'm not so sure if the sub above is "bullet proof", because maybe the data in the looped sheet is already contains something like this :
651 with entry_month 4
651 with entry_month 9
661 with entry_month 7
661 with entry_month 5
661 with entry_month 3

Say for example in sheet configure, the data is : 651 - 661 - 3
So when the sub run, in the looped sheet it find 651 ... 
then it check if 661 is already in the looped sheet or not... 
it find out that 661 is already there (the c variable is not nothing) ---> this will be the the first 661 found cell in the looped sheet with entry_month 7

then it check if the found (c.row, MonthCol) value is the same with entry month from sheet Configure (3 from the example) or not. Because 7 <> 3 then it won't flag cek = false, the "if" continue and flag cek as true continue the replace-copy-paste process. Resulting like this :
651 with entry_month 4
651 with entry_month 9
661 with entry_month 7
661 with entry_month 5
661 with entry_month 3
661 with entry_month 3 (addition data, changing 651 to 661 entry_month 4 to 3)
661 with entry_month 3 (addition data, changing 651 to 661 entry_month 9 to 3)

So if the data in the looped sheet like the example above and you don't want the result to be like that, then the sub is not "bullet proof".

The sub then need to be revised, to check the entry_month value of each row in column B of the looped sheet with 661 value by looping or find-next method. From the example above, so at the third iteration, it then find out that the third found cell contains 661 in column B of the looped sheet - its entry_month is 3 (the same with the one in sheet Configure), then it flag cek = false, no replace-copy-paste process.

Comment: This part of code does not find cells:                                                                                                                  
                ```With sh.Columns(2)
                .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
                Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -1)
                RC = Application.CountIf(sh.Columns(2), True)
                .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            End With ```

Comment: @Wassle, did you mean that for example the cell value is 651, but in the looped sheet column 2 there is no 651 at all?

Comment: no, no I pasted this code and it identifies range incorrectly in variable rg, the rest of the code is fine. In the table I have good SPcodes inserted 651 (such as are also in the data) and i have bug `1004 cells not found.

Comment: At what line it throw u the error? At replace line ? Or at set rg line?

Comment: Sth is with wrong with row set rg = .SpecialCells....

Comment: Please add `sh.activate` right after `If sh.Name <> "Config" And sh.Name <> "Summary" Then`. Then step run the sub, and see if something happen on the active sheet after the yellow indicator pass `.Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False`. And please never save your workbook if you test run the sub in your original workbook. Better make a copy first, then test run the sub in the copied version.

Comment: Still the same error https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GwaBEDpkLpOoYQ9SYznXTzTBHv3TotVW?usp=sharing here i paste my macro if u want see this file

Comment: I've checked your sample workbook. For the first looped sheet, I think the code run OK. I'm sorry I didn't notice that your header start on row2. So I change the code to "A2" in LC variable. But even after I put the if to check if the looped cell is found in the looped sheet, I don't think the code can run properly to the rest of the sheet, because I see that the ENTRY MONTH in some sheet is in column F but in some other sheet is in column H. Sorry.

Comment: I need to revise the code to check where is the column of entry month on the looped sheet. But this also I'm not sure if the text "entry month" in the header of each sheet is consistent or not. If not consistent, then the code also can't work.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to add some line based on your sample workbook to find where the ENTRY_MONTH column in the looped sheet.

Comment: In the meantime, please have a look to the revised code in my answer. Just copy it again replacing my old sub you've already tried. Don't forget to bring back the 651 value from TRUE in your sample workbook sheet BUB22I.rpt before run the sub. At least for the first looped sheet, the code should work without error, because it didn't throw error in my side with your sample workbook first looped sheet. Step run it.

Comment: i checked it and now is good i just forgot about bring back values and that was the main problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to finish the code and i paste the solution below**

```
Sub NB_TOOL()
Dim rgSteer As Range: Dim rg As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim cell As Range
Dim RC As Long: Dim LC As Long
Dim rgDest As Range: Dim i As Long
Dim c As Integer
Dim s As Range
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "ENTRY_MONTH"

With Sheets("Config")
Set rgSteer = .Range("L4", .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Config" And sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
    LC = sh.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        For Each cell In rgSteer
            With sh.Columns(2)
                .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
                Set rg = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -1)
                On Error GoTo 0
                RC = Application.CountIf(sh.Columns(2), True)
                .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            End With
                       
            If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            
            For i = 1 To LC - 1
            Set rg = Union(rg, rg.Offset(0, 1))
            Next i
            
            Set rgDest = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set rgDest = rgDest.Resize(RC, LC)
            rg.Copy Destination:=rgDest
            rgDest.Columns(2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            
            Set s = sh.Rows(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchFormat:=False)
            If Not s Is Nothing Then
             c = s.Column
            End If
            rgDest.Columns(c).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you @karma for huge help :)

Yesterday I managed to solve all the missing topics by myself :)

Comment: Glad that finally you can solve the problem. BTW, I see that if you accidently run the code twice where the spcode and entry_month in sheet Configure still the same when you run the sub previously, it will do the copy-paste again, resulting your "added" data is double. Just an idea, to avoid the "accidently", maybe you can do a true-false boolean first. So, soon after `for each cell in rgSteer`, you check first if the looped cell.offset(0,1) value is found in column B of the looped sheet. (continue)

Comment: If it is, then check if the row of the found cell (where the value is the looped cell.offset(0,1)  - entry_month column value is the same with the looped cell.offset(0,2) value. If it's the same then flag it as FALSE. So before the "replace" process, you put something like `if cek = TRUE then` do the "replace, copy-paste" process, then `end if`. But I don't know if maybe it's actually it is expected to have double "addition" data, by not changing the previous value of spcode-the_replacement-entry_month in sheet Configure and run the sub again.

Comment: U have right with this dual-data i checked that and this ismy miss, but honesty i how do this loop ;/ because I can't understand exactly what you are writing to me how to do it

Comment: In short, it will do the "replace - copy - paste" process when it does find the spcode value from sheet configure (the looped cell value) in the looped sheet column B, but it doesn't find the spcode replacement and the entry_month from sheet configure in the looped sheet. Please have a look to my edited answer with the comment in the sub.